# How does one cycle through a HashMap <String, Object> and pass certain objects into a List based on their attributes for printing to the console?

Tags: java

The constraints of the project require me to use a `HashMap` as my source of data. I'm being asked to make the following method

`getAccountsWithMinimum` - returns a `List` of `Account`s that have at least the specified balance

The problem is that HashMaps have no index. So it's not like I can use a For loop to go through it.

I tried adapting code from similar questions I found on Stack Overflow and GeeksForGeeks. This approach not only hasn't worked but doesn't much benefit me as I don't understand WHY it works even if it did (It doesn't).

I tried using this from code I found on GeeksForGeeks. It prints nothing.

```
    public void getAccountsWithMinumum() {
        Iterator entries = accounts.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            Integer key = (Integer) entry.getKey();
            Integer value = (Integer) entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
        } 
    }
```

The objects in accounts hold (String)firstName, (String)lastName, (double)balance, (String)accountType, and (String)AccountID attributes.

What I'd like to get is something that returns the desired list and prints it to the console so that I can confirm it.

I don't need someone to do this FOR me per say as I doubt this is the last time that I'll be asked to do this or something similar. Either some really heavy hand holding hints so I can fill in the gaps or if its easier just to do it a detailed explanation of WHY I'm doing it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `accounts` is not empty?

Comment: I have a TestBed Class with a Main method that adds several entries to it before the method is called to avoid exactly this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Java 8 streams:

```
List<Accout> accounts = accounts.values().stream()        
    .filter(account -> account.getBalance() > threshold)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

With `foreach`:

```
List<Account> accountsWithMinimum = new ArrayList<>();
for (Account acccount : accounts.values() ) {
    if (account.balance > threshold) {
        accountsWithMinimum.add(account);
    }
}
```

The `values` method of the `Map` interface returns a `Collection` of the values stored in the map. You can also used `entrySet` to get the collection of key-value pairs, or `keySet` to get only the keys.

Comment: The second block looks just like what I'll need. Combined with the information from @Erwin Smout I think that should just about do it.

Comment: I was able to set that forEach inside my method replacing threshold with a parameter. However I can't figure out what would go in place of .values. It claims "The method values() is undefined for type List<Account>". I tried placing this same for loop outside of the code block just to see and it doesn't report any problems at all. Its only when I attempt to contain it within the method that I get an issue.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. You need to call the `values` method on the `Map`, not on the newly created `List` - let me update my answer.

Comment: Then `add` should be applied to `accountsWithMinimum` as well

Comment: So yeah your code works. Its mine that doesn't. I added a bit outside the if statement and got all my values printed. So apparently the balance isn't setting properly and its only been told to print accounts over a certain balance. Thanks again!

Comment: This is from just last year. I can hardly believe I was trying to treat a list and a dictionary the same at that time.

Answer (score 0):

From information you provided best solution seems to be change data from HashMap to [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), that keep ordering.

If you take a close took to javadoc, you can find following part useful:

> his implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally
>   chaotic ordering provided by HashMap (and Hashtable), without
>   incurring the increased cost associated with TreeMap. It can be used
>   to produce a copy of a map that has the same order as the original,
>   regardless of the original map's implementation:
>
> ```
>  void foo(Map m) {
>      Map copy = new LinkedHashMap(m);
>      ...
>  }
> ```
>
> This technique is particularly useful if a module takes a map on
>   input, copies it, and later returns results whose order is determined
>   by that of the copy. (Clients generally appreciate having things
>   returned in the same order they were presented.)

So the idea is to get in input the map, create a LinkedHashMap over it, iterate using forEach. Here an example with comments where you can start to elaborate on it

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.test();
    }

    private void test() {
        // your input
        HashMap<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();
        accounts.put(0, new Account("first", 1));
        accounts.put(1, new Account("second", 10));
        accounts.put(2, new Account("third", 5));
        // call your method
        List<Account> result = getAccountsWithMinumum(accounts);
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    private List<Account> getAccountsWithMinumum(HashMap<Integer, Account> accounts) {
        List<Account> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // create linkedhashmap to get order
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Account> data = new LinkedHashMap<>(accounts);
        // get entries
        for (Entry<Integer, Account> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            // print entry
            System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
            // check account balanece on a value, for example 6 (use it as parameter!)
            if (entry.getValue().balance < 6) {
                // add to the result list
                result.add(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // your account class
    private class Account {

        public String name;
        public int balance;

        public Account(String name, int balance) {
            this.name = name;
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[name=" + name + ", balance=" + balance + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Your answer is a little bit difficult to answer because of lack of what Hashmap is exactly, in my case is

Comment: OP does not need an index per se. He is simply not used to iterations over not ordered collections.

Comment: @PM77-1 is correct. I don't need an index. An index is just the way I most understand. Also the project requirements dictate that I use a HashMap. A linked HashMap, despite the virtues you've extolled, would not work in this instance because of the project outline/prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The example you found predates the use of generics in Java.  Any Map is these days actually a Map<K,V>, where K is the type (= the class) of the keys in the mapping, and V is the type (once again the java class) of the value objects the key values are mapped to.  So the Map in your example (looking at what types the objects are cast to) would these days be written as Map<Integer,Integer>.

There are some distinct ways of iterating over the contents of a Map : iterating its entrySet(), iterating its keySet() or iterating its values().

The first results in objects of type Map.Entry (as in the example) from which you can subsequently retrieve both the key object and the value object.

The second results in objects of type K (type of the key) and will obviously give you only the key objects leaving you no access to the corresponding value object (except by using map.get(key) which is rather stupid given that you're already iterating and could have had the value object "for free").

The third results in objects of type V (type/class of the value objects), without access to the corresponding key, except if the map has been built using key objects from within the value objects.

Assuming your Account objects are the value objects, I'd guess you'd want to iterate over the values() and then check each returned object's getBalance().

Or you can use the more modern lambda-style syntax using streams, as has been sugested in other answers.

Was this the kind of "explanation" you were looking for ?

Comment: It was. I appreciate it. The response here was prompt and in depth. I'm still digesting most of it but I think this will do nicely. I have several other like methods I should be able to perform on my own now. Thanks everyone!